# How I can update getfeautreinfourl query based on checked layers on ol-layerswitcher(ol-ext)?

Tags: openlayers, layer-switcher

I'm using ol-layerswitcher from [ol-ext](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/), But I don't know why I can get information from unchecked or removed layers from layer switcher
[image]

, I am going to popup information that will be able for only checked layer.

```
/**
 * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
 */


var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250,
  },
});


/**
 * Add a click handler to hide the popup.
 * @return {boolean} Don't follow the href.
 */
closer.onclick = function () {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

var wmsLayersSources=[];
var queryLayers = [];
 $("#listLayers").change(function(){
     var selectProject = $("#projectname-selected option:selected").text();
          var index = projects.indexOf(`${selectProject}`);
          var geoServerWs = ws[index];

 var layers_ =($("#listLayers").val())
 
 console.log('layers_',layers_)
 if(layers_ === undefined){
     alert('Not Selected Any Layers')
 }else{

     var wmsLayers=[
     new ol.layer.Image({
         title:`${layers_}`,
           visible: true,
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
       url: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/${geoServerWs}/wms`,
       params: {'LAYERS': `${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`},
 ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.open('GET', src);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(`${geoUserName}` + ':' + `${geoPass}`));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                image.getImage().onload = function() {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
                    
    };
    image.getImage().src = objectURL;
  };
  xhr.send();
},
     
      
      })
   })
];
console.log('wmsLayers  ',wmsLayers[0])
    map.addLayer(wmsLayers[0]);
    var wmsSource =[]
    wmsSource.push(wmsLayers[0])
    wmsSource.forEach(element=>{
    wmsLayersSources.push(element.getSource())
  

    })
      queryLayers.push(`${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`)
   console.log('wmsLayersSource ', wmsLayersSources)
   console.log('queryLayers ', queryLayers)
     
}

/////Map LayerSwitcher/////


  // Control Select 
  var select = new ol.interaction.Select({});
  map.addInteraction(select);

  // On selected => show/hide popup
  select.getFeatures().on(['add'], function(e) {
    var feature = e.element;
    var content = "";
    content += "<img src='"+feature.get("img")+"'/>";
    content += feature.get("text");
    popup.show(feature.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate(), content); 
  });
  select.getFeatures().on(['remove'], function(e) {
    popup.hide(); 
  })

 
 
    // Add control inside the map
    var ctrl = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher();
    map.addControl(ctrl);
    ctrl.on('toggle', function(e) {
        console.log('Collapse layerswitcher', e.collapsed);
    });

    // Add a layer switcher outside the map
    var switcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        target: $(".layerSwitcher").get(0),
        // displayInLayerSwitcher: function(l) { return false; },
        show_progress: true,
        extent: true,
        trash: true,
        oninfo: function(l) { alert(l.get("title")); }
    });
  
    // Add a new button to the list 
    switcher.on('drawlist', function(e) {
        var layer = e.layer;
        $('<div>').text('?') // addClass('layerInfo')
            .click(function() {
                alert(layer.get('title'));
            })
            .appendTo($('> .ol-layerswitcher-buttons', e.li));
    });
    // Add a button to show/hide the layers
    var button = $('<div class="toggleVisibility" title="show/hide">')
        .text("Show/hide all")
        .click(function() {
            var a = map.getLayers().getArray();
           
            
            var b = !a[0].getVisible();
            if (b) button.removeClass("show");
            else button.addClass("show");
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i].setVisible(b);

            }

        });


    switcher.setHeader($('<div>').append(button).get(0))
        

    map.addControl(switcher);
    // Insert mapbox layer in layer switcher
    function displayInLayerSwitcher(b) {
        mapbox.set('displayInLayerSwitcher', b);
    }



////Map pointer and 
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
    //document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML ='';
    $('#popup-content').html = '';

var queryLayers =''
     
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate
  //$('#popup-content').html =''
   var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution(); 

  
 
   wmsLayersSources.forEach(function(value, i){
       console.log('value ', value)
       console.log('value ',value.getFeatureInfoUrl)
     
     
      queryLayers = `${value["params_"].LAYERS}` //${(i<value.length -1) ?',' :''}
    console.log('querylayers is equal ', queryLayers)
    



var url = value["getFeatureInfoUrl"](
    evt.coordinate,
    viewResolution,
     'EPSG:3857',
   {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html','QUERY_LAYERS':`${queryLayers}`},
);
    
if (url) {
    //headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa('username' + ":" + 'password'));
    fetch(url, { 
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'text/html', 
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' +btoa(`${geoUserName}:${geoPass}`),
        
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }),
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    }).then(function (response) {
         //console.log(response)
     
         return response.text()

         
          
      }).then(function(html) {
         
  
 $('#popup-content').html(html)

 
          });


 //end if



   }
   })
   overlay.setPosition(coordinate);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using all your WMS sources

```
   wmsLayersSources.forEach(function(value, i){
```

Only use sources which are in visible layers

```
   wmsLayers.forEach(function(layer, i){
       if (layer.getVisible()) {
           const value = layer.getSource();
           queryLayers = `${value["params_"].LAYERS}`
       }
       ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much,your answer is good, But when I did add only one layer or even I add some layers when I did uncheck all of them, last layers that unchecked and remaind in layer switcher list  or even  when it removed from layer switcher it can get return info! https://imgur.com/undefined